# ¿Alguien me daría una explicación de este código porfavor?

Tags: c++

Mi profesor de Estructuras de Datos me ha estado enseñando a programar pilas y filas, pero en vez de como usualmente he visto, el ha creado librerías específicamente para esto, y la verdad, no entiendo mucho, y menos encuentro dónde estudiar bien el tema. Sería genial si me dieran un resumen de este con palabras sencillas, y videos o páginas donde expliquen mejor qué se está haciendo aquí.

ListStack.cpp

```
#include "ListStack.hpp"
#include <cstdlib>
ListStack::ListStack()
{
    _top = NULL;
    _size = 0;
}
 
void ListStack::push(eleS_t e)
{
    nodeS * nodeAux;
    nodeAux = (nodeS*)malloc(sizeof(nodeS));
    nodeAux->e = e;
    nodeAux->next = _top;
    _top= nodeAux;
    _size++;
}
int ListStack::size()
{
    return _size;
}
```

ListStack.hpp

```
#include "iStack.hpp"
struct nodeS{
    eleS_t e;
    nodeS * next;
};
class ListStack : public iStack
{
    private:
        nodeS * _top;
        int _size;
    public:
        ListStack();
        void push(eleS_t);
        void pop();
        eleS_t top();
        int size();
        bool empty();
        ~ListStack();
};
```

iStack.hpp

```
#ifndef ISTACK_HPP
#define ISTACK_HPP
typedef int eleS_t;
class iStack
{
    public:
        virtual void push(eleS_t )=0;
        virtual void pop()=0;
        virtual eleS_t top()=0;
        virtual int size()=0;
        virtual bool empty()=0;
};
 
#endif
```

cient.cpp

```
#include "ListStack.hpp"
 
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    ListStack * ls = new ListStack();
    ls->push(5);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `Sería genial si me dieran un resumen de este con palabras sencillas, y videos o páginas donde expliquen mejor qué se está haciendo aquí.` Para videos: `https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=estructura+de+datos+C%2B%2B` también  `https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=estructura+de+datos+C+plus+plus` Cosa de ver el contenido, te sugiero que por cada tema, fijo tengas más 1 fuente de conocimiento, de preferencia 4 autores para que tengas un mejor panorama.

Comment: Bienvenido. En primer lugar, el código escrito en C es compatible con el de C++ pero no al revés. Son lenguajes diferentes. En segundo lugar, es mucho para explicar. Centra la pregunta en algunas cosas que no sepas. Por ejemplo: ¿Para qué sirve `typedef` y cómo se usa? o ¿Para qué sirve `new`? Ciertamente podrías averiguar esas cosas en google. Aquí tienes una lista de reproducción sobre C++ altamente recomendable: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLlrATfBNZ98dudnM48yfGUldqGD0S4FFb

Comment: @Matthew _"el código escrito en C es compatible con C++"_ -  Eso puede haber sido cierto hace mucho tiempo, pero ya no lo es.

Comment: @TedLyngmo la mayoría del código C es compatible con C++ ... son únicamente un número limitado (creciente pero bastante limitado) de características

Comment: @eferion Bueno, las matrices flexibles y las matrices de longitud variable son dos grandes diferencias que ni siquiera se compilarán en C++ estricto, pero lo que es peor, el tamaño de una estructura vacía es 0 en C y 1 en C++, lo que puede generar errores muy confusos. También hay muchas palabras clave en C++ que se pueden usar como nombres de variables en C. Las conversiones implícitas de `void*` a punteros a tipos es otra diferencia. Hay demasiadas diferencias para poder decir que el código escrito en C es compatible con C++.

Comment: @TedLyngmo la realidad es que muchos compiladores dan soporte a los VLA, pese a no estar permitidos por ninguno de los dos estándares. Para todo lo demás, cierto. Sin embargo no hay que olvidar también la gran cantidad de funciones y elementos que sí que son comunes a ambos lenguajes. Al final el que las diferencias sean muchas o pocas es algo relativo. Lo cierto es que se pueden escribir programas más o menos complejos y completos usando únicamente características comunes a C y C++. Aun así yo soy de los primeros que critica las preguntas que incluyen ambas etiquetas alegremente

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo en que tienen muchas cosas en común. El soporte de VLA era obligatorio en C99 pero se convirtió en opcional en C11. Sin embargo, nunca han sido parte de C ++, pero algunas implementaciones los admiten como una extensión si uno está dispuesto a abandonar el modo `-pedantic`. Simplemente tengo una reacción alérgica cuando alguien insinúa que C es simplemente un subconjunto de C++ :-) Tiene palabras clave y mecanismos únicos, como selecciones `_Generic`, inicializadores designados no triviales, etc.